# How to hide a pre-filled question on google forms using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-engine, google-forms, google-forms-api

I want to hide a pre-filled question so that it will still be automatically filled, but will not be visible to the user while they are responding to the form. This is to keep confidential information hidden and to simplify the form's appearance.
I tried to run some scripts like this one, but none of them worked as expected so far.

Comment: `I tried to run some scripts like this one, but none of them worked as expected so far.` Would you please include one or more of the scripts that you tried and provide a reference for the source.

Comment: `I want to hide a pre-filled question` Please excuse my confusion... You haven't described the question or answer to be pre-filled, and this might (or not) be significant - one cannot comment unless you provide more information about your scenario, as well as the question and answer. OTOH, if you pre-fill an answer to a question AND if you don't show the question or the answer to the respondent, what is the point of including the question in the first instance?

Comment: function hideQuestion() {
      var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
      var items = form.getItems();
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item.getTitle() == "Question" && item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
          item.asListItem().setVisible(false);
        }
      }
    }

Comment: @Tedinoz I want to make this answer hidden or immutable so that the user cannot change the project ID while filling out the form. This ID will only be used for documentation purposes.

Comment: `.setVisible(false)` Would you please provide a url for the documentation on this method.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAOK63QPm5OOT0frzMhfyl24gKd_x4UXvpds4sTQcJX8qCqg/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1495303891=ID+-+project+2

Comment: I got this script through ChatGPT, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: I'm trying to solve using this sample document, I will have access to the project soon.

Comment: `so that the user cannot change the project ID while filling out the form. This ID will only be used for documentation purposes.` OK but we know nothing about your scenario. You can **NOT** hide an item, so if you require more help you you need to provide more information, including (not limited to) your scenario, how the ID is used, submission frequency, submission numbers, resubmission?, tracking of users?, "linking" a project to a form, whether the user _knows_ which Project a form relates to, why not create multiple identical forms (one for each project), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do what you're trying to accomplish and this is likely intentional on Google's part. While I don't know EXACTLY what your requirement is, it could be used to track individual data about users' submissions *without them being aware of it.*  Google (and Microsoft) seem committed to properly apprising form users when their submissions are and are not anonymous. As a result, there are certain roadblocks you might encounter such as....

1. A pre-filled form must have the pre-populated link within the URL. You could try to trick someone by using a shortened link, but the identification will still be in the URL after it loads. It will appear after the `...viewform` with a `?` after it with the exact item ID and response. It disappears once loaded, so maybe you could get around it using link shortener, but it would still be visible to the user.
2. One workaround that I just considered was having a section that the form skipped, but had a pre-populated URL. So if you had three sections, and section 1 jumpted to section 3 with section 2 having the pre-written URL... it does not work, meaning the pre-populated information is not part of the form response.

Comment: I agree with everything that you said, but the OP hasn't mentioned a URL - they just said `This is to keep confidential information hidden and to simplify the form's appearance`. I did wonder whether the OP was trying to create some kind of responseURL, but that is just speculation. It really begs the question of WHY hide a pre-filled question at all. Or put another way, what is the objective of the OP's question?